# Google app engine how to schedule Crons one after another

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Hi um struggling with a problem . I created number of crons and i and i want to run them one after another in a specific order . Lets say i have A , B , C and D crons and want to Run Cron B after Completion of Cron A and after that want to run Cron D and after that cron C. I searched for a way to accomplish this task but could not find any . Can any one help?

Comment: Then schedule only the A job, and have it start the B job itself afterwards. cron jobs are purely time-based and cannot be made inter-dependent on each other via cron.

Comment: Hoping reality will change to suit you is not a viable method of solving the problem. If you need to run the jobs in order, then schedule only one job and have it run the others when it completes.

Comment: Chain of Responsibility pattern may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using crons, then I'm guessing you've defined endpoints that the cron runner will call...

Use the cron runner to start task A, and let it [add a task in the task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/) to run B after it finishes. Repeat for B and C.

You can probably use the same endpoints that you used for the cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Though I agree with suggestions in comment, I think I have a better solution to your problem (Hopefully :))

Although it's not necessary you can use pull queue in your application, to facilitate design of your problem. The pattern I am suggesting is like this:

1) A servlet centrally handles execution (Let's call it controller) of various tasks and is exposed at a URL

2) The jobs are initiated by the controller by hitting the URL of the job (Assuming pull queue again)

3) After job completion, the job hits back at controller URL to report completion of job

4) Controller in turn deletes the job from queue which is done, and adds next logical job to queue

And this is repeated.

In this case your job code is unchanged even if logic of sequence changes or new jobs are added. You might need to make changes to controller only.